# Unable to install Python argon2_cffi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, argon2-ffi

I am trying to install argon2_cffi in my python 3.5 virtual environment without using pip. I have downloaded the package from [github](https://github.com/hynek/argon2_cffi/) . When I am trying to install this ,

**python setup.py build or install** , it fails with the error

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating src/argon2_cffi.egg-info
writing requirements to src/argon2_cffi.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/argon2_cffi.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to src/argon2_cffi.egg-
info/dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to src/argon2_cffi.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'src/argon2_cffi.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'src/argon2_cffi.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src/argon2/_ffi.py'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.gitmodules'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'extras/libargon2/.git'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under 
directory 'tests'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
writing manifest file 'src/argon2_cffi.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running build_clib
building 'libargon2' library
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-
prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-
security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -msse2 -
Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c 
extras/libargon2/src/argon2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-
3.5/extras/libargon2/src/argon2.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: extras/libargon2/src/argon2.c: No such 
file or directory
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution

First download the all depended packages using, after activate your virtualevn

```
pip download argon2-cffi==16.3.0
```

after running this command you will get all files depends with argon2, it will download following files

```
argon2_cffi-16.3.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl,
cffi-1.11.5-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl and 
six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

after that just install argon2 package, just type

```
pip install argon2_cffi-16.3.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
```

it works for me...